# Needing to simply check two columns against one another and out put what is different

Tags: vba, excel

You would think that this question has been answered before but I can not locate 1 person who has had to do this this way. I have Two sheets being compared for dates only on column A starting at A3. If the second sheet's Column A is missing a Date then I want it to just output that date starting at I3 of the second sheet. I feel like it is super simple but the code I have pieced together always messes up. [SHEET 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/37SWU.png)

[SHEET 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aT4bN.png)

If anyone wants the Code Ill gladly upload it, but I don't think it is correct at ALL.

```
Sub jim()
Dim CompareRange As Variant, To_Be_Compared As Variant, x As Variant, y As Variant

Range("A").Select
Selection.End(xlDown).Select
Set To_Be_Compared = Range("ALPHA!A3:" & Selection.Address)
Range("B").Select
Selection.End(xlDown).Select
Set CompareRange = Range("OUTPUT!A3:" & Selection.Address)



i = 1
To_Be_Compared.Select

For Each x In Selection
    For Each y In CompareRange
        If x = y Then
          Range("I3" & i).Value = x
          i = i + 1
        End If
    Next y
Next x
End Sub
```

[image: OP's sample]

Comment: So far this sounds like an Excel usage scenario -- in other words, use Excel formulas and don't use code.  Are you sure you want a VBA solution?

Comment: Yes, show the code, we might be able to offer a simple fix.

Comment: Believe me I suck at this and wish i could just use a formula, but i need it in a list format without the false cells.

Comment: This is my 3rd day with VBA and I dont quite understand the syntax quite yet haha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some variant arrays and [dictionary objects](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251825.aspx) should make quick work of isolating the orphaned dates.

```
Sub bert()
    Dim v As Long, vALPHAs As Variant, vOUTs As Variant, dTMPs As Object, dOUTs As Object

    Set dOUTs = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Set dTMPs = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    dOUTs.CompareMode = vbTextCompare
    dTMPs.CompareMode = vbTextCompare

    With Worksheets("alpha")
        vALPHAs = .Range(.Cells(3, 1), .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 1)).Value
    End With

    With Worksheets("output")
        vOUTs = .Range(.Cells(3, 1), .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)).Value

        For v = LBound(vOUTs, 1) To UBound(vOUTs, 1)
            If Not dOUTs.Exists(vOUTs(v, 1)) Then _
                dOUTs.Add Key:=vOUTs(v, 1), Item:=vOUTs(v, 1)
        Next v

        For v = LBound(vALPHAs, 1) To UBound(vALPHAs, 1)
            If Not dOUTs.Exists(vALPHAs(v, 1)) Then _
                dTMPs.Add Key:=vALPHAs(v, 1), Item:=vALPHAs(v, 2)
        Next v
        If CBool(dTMPs.Count) Then
            v = .Cells(Rows.Count, 9).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
            .Cells(v, 9).Resize(dTMPs.Count, 1) = Application.Transpose(dTMPs.keys)
            'optionally bring across the names from column B
            '.Cells(v, 10).Resize(dTMPs.Count, 1) = Application.Transpose(dTMPs.items)
        End If
    End With

    dOUTs.RemoveAll: Set dOUTs = Nothing
    dTMPs.RemoveAll: Set dTMPs = Nothing

End Sub
```

If you have a LOT of dates to collect, the app [TRANSPOSE function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/TRANSPOSE-function-ED039415-ED8A-4A81-93E9-4B6DFAC76027) might overload but that would have to be in the tens of thousands (>65,536 orphaned dates).

Comment: If no one tells you this today @Jeeped, You are a beautiful person! Thank you so much that did the trick!!

Comment: Thank you everyone for taking time to help the newbie Coder. Have a great week guys!!